# When the apparent Upstairs uses their central heating

Tags: heater

Upstairs uses their central heatingWhen the neighbors upstairs and use their central heating it affects my apartment blowing air into my apartment is this supposed to happen

Comment: Welcome. Some punctuation up there (to make sentences) would be just great.

Comment: Did you ask the landlord?